# How can I compile and run my C code from within Emacs like I would with the terminal?

Tags: c, compilation, term

I recently moved from Code::Blocks to Emacs to write C code.

The one thing I don't like (because it takes too much time and effort for a simple and repetitive task) is the fact that I can't compile/build the code from within the software itself. So in order to compile, link and run my code I have to switch between Emacs and the terminal.

However, my professor said to me that I should be able to compile from Emacs itself by calling a buffer as a terminal, then compile and run the code like I would on my Linux terminal.

I've been searching on how to do this quite a bit now, but still couldn't figure it out. So I guess my question is: how can I compile and run my C code from within Emacs like I would with the terminal?

Comment: Does the Emacs manual, node [Compilation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation.html) help? `C-h r` followed by `i compile` takes you there.

Answer (score 4):

I use the `compile` command, and also add a `run` target to my makefile like this

```
program: program.cpp
    gcc program.cpp -o program

run: program
     program
```

So you can just use `make run` to compile and run it

Comment: Alternatively there is the [quickrun package](https://melpa.org/#/quickrun), which is handy for running programs directly with many other languages also

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>M-!</kbd> let's you type a shell command and <kbd>M-x shell</kbd> takes you to a shell window. I'd probably set up makefile/CMake and run that.

Also if you install flycheck it should show you live if there are any errors in the file.

Answer (score 0):

In order to simply compile a program you can use the built-in `compile` command.

To do this you need to have a `makefile` file in your current directory, then simply run `M-x compile`. A minibuffer will open where you can enter the name of the file you are trying to compile. Once you hit `RET`, a new buffer will pop open, reporting any errors or warnings while compiling, or a success message if none were found. It'll also point you to where in the source file the program failed to compile!

To read more about it, see the Emacs manual (`C-h r`), node [Compilation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation.html).

Comment: If the compilation process is very simple (e.g. `gcc myprogram.c -o myprogram`) you can skip the makefile and write the command in the variable `compile-command`, set as a file local variable